# how to align the text in CheckedTextView with checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

My definition XML is:

```
<CheckedTextView android:textSize="18.0dip" 
    android:text="@string/text" 
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:id="@+id/test" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark" />
```

Everything works fine but
the text always at the top left of the view and the checkbox is center vertical.
They are not at the same line.
How to align them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add this line

`android:gravity="center_vertical"`